# Отображение меток по этажам

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть множество меток, есть 5 типов карт (в моем случае это этажи здания), есть меню с фильтром меток, это все работает. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы я нажимал, например, на 1 значок(который показывает или скрывает метки) со всеми музеями на всех этажах, а метки отображались в зависимости от выбранного этажа. При переключении между типами, метки предыдущего этажа должны скрываться, а метки нового этажа показываться.
Писал я вопрос уже. Ответили, что можно как-то через setfilter в обджект менеджер, но каким образом прикрутить типы карт туда не могу понять. Документацию смотрел, не смог найти практически ничего по моему вопросу.
Если можно, хотелось бы увидеть небольшой пример 
Спасибо!)

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите пример кода и сформулируйте вопрос более конкретно. слишком общие вопросы вида "сделайте за меня" противоречат правилам сервиса

Comment: Какую именно часть кода вам привести? Я не могу понять, как и куда прикрутить сетфильтр, чтобы он работал с определенным типом карты

Comment: Вы можете определять тип карты методом `myMap.getType()` и в зависимости от типа карты фильтровать объекты по нужным признакам. Как именно работает setFilter показано [в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter?from=SO). В примере фильтр выставляется при выборе элемента  в выпадающем списке, а вы будете следить за выбором этажа.

Фактически вам нужно добавить второе условие - при выборе фильтра или смене этажа выставлять фильтр сразу по двум признакам.

Comment: Если можно в ЛС связываться тут, давайте туда. За наводку спасибо, бужу пробовать!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего описания получается, что есть два условия фильтрации: категория объекта (музей) и этаж, где объект расположен. То есть все объекты должны иметь признак, который будет показывать принадлежность этажу, допустим `properties.level` и признак, отвечающий за категорию, допустим `properties.type`.

Тогда при выборе этажа вам нужно фильтровать объекты по этажу:

```
objectManager.setFilter('properties.level == "3"')
```

Если на этаже выбрана категория объектов, нужно делать фильтрацию по двум признакам:

```
objectManager.setFilter('properties.level == "3" && properties.type == "музей"')
```

И так далее, при выборе пользователем этажей/категорий объектов.

Как именно использовать фильтры в менеджере объектов [показано в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter?from=SO).

Comment: Выбор этажа происходит вместо "Схема, спутник, гибрид". А вы предлагаете, как я понял, сделать подкатегории в выпадающем списке.

Comment: можно самим объектам задать принадлежность этажу, а можно в зависимости от этажа выводить разные метки на карту и уже их фильтровать только по категории. тут единственно правильного ответа нет - на ваш вкус

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Comment: Удалось подключить фильтр по этажам к типам карты! Спасибо большое за помощь! Вопрос остался для меня открытым в том, что есть 4 этажа, на них по иконке, все иконки должны появляться\исчезать по нажатию на кнопку в специальном меню, но каждая на своем этаже. Как заставить фильтр иконок видеть, какой тип карты сейчас выбран? Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше завести про это отдельный вопрос и привести часть своего кода, где не получается настроить желаемое поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос: Фильтрация по слоям(типам карты) typeselector.

В коллекции задаем новый properties - "level". Задаем значение "3 этаж", к примеру. При добавлении слоя к типам карты тоже указываем название. В моем случае my#mapTypeA равно "3 этаж". И дальше подключаем фильтрацию по level.

```
var typeSelector = new ymaps.control.TypeSelector({

     data: {
            content: 'Этажи'
        },
        mapTypes: [
            'my#mapTypeA',
            'my#mapTypeB',
            'my#mapTypeC',
            'my#mapTypeD',
            'my#mapTypeE'
        ]
    });

typeSelector.options.set('position', {top: 10, right: 170});
typeSelector.options.set('fixTitle', false);

map.controls.add(typeSelector);

      // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
    typeSelector.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxLevelItems = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, typeSelector.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxLevelItems.data.get('content')] = listBoxLevelItems.isSelected();
        typeSelector.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(typeSelector.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
        objectKabinetsManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.properties.level;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }
```