# Подписи кабинетов, этажей, улиц и домов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть здание офиса. Большое. В нем 5 этажей и более 1000 кабинетов. Вопрос: как можно вывести подписи этих кабинетов? Не понимаю, как сделать через коллекции, если это возможно, потому что инициализировать каждую надпись с использованием templateLayoutFactory невозможно из-за количества. Нужна коллекция(возможно, что-то другое) с подключением 1 пресета с заданными цветом текста, шрифта и т.д.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно отобразить подписи кабинетов через метки. Для этого нужно создать собственный макет метки и назначить его всем подписям разом. Данные для отображения в подписях хранить отдельно.

В этом вопросе решали похожую задачу: [Отображение меток по этажам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777766/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Comment: Что значит "Отдельно"?

Comment: например, в этом примере для меток, которые описаны в JSON, задаётся зеленый пресет https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager. Аналогично, вы можете один раз описать шаблон и задать его всем объектам, которые будут добавлены.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем собственный пресет, где вместо url иконки - пустое значение

`ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('game#KabIcon', {
             iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: '',
            iconImageOffset: [-15, -15],
        });`

В html создаем стиль, где описываем размеры, размеры шрифта, цвет шрифта и т.д.

```
.kabinet_layout { 
            position: absolute;
            width: 130px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            color: blue;
        }
```

В коллекции создаем точку, в которой указываем данные балуна, хинта, и iconContent, в котором указываем div с нашем классом "стиля". Так же указываем наш пресет

```
var kabinetsData = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 01112345678901, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates":  [0.0698986, -0.0551758]}, "properties": {"level": "3 Этаж", "iconContent": "<div class='kabinet_layout'>Кабинет 3-09А</div>"}, "options": {"preset": "game#KabIcon"}},
     ]
};
```